# Error in sql developer

Tags: sql, oracle

```
create table Blog
(
blog_id NUMBER(8,0),
blog_name VARCHAR2(255) not null,
status VARCHAR2(50) DEFAULT 'PENDING',
create_date DATE default sysDate,
description CLOB not null,
no_of_likes NUMBER(5),
no_of comments NUMBER(5),
no_of_views NUMBER(5),
user_id NUMBER(8,0),

CONSTRAINT pk_blog_blog_id PRIMARY KEY (blog_id),
CONSTRAINT fk_blog_user_id FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES USER_DETAILS (user_id)
);
```

---

```
Error starting at line : 1 in command -
create table Blog
(
blog_id NUMBER(8,0),
blog_name VARCHAR2(255) not null,
status VARCHAR2(50) DEFAULT 'PENDING',
create_date DATE default sysDate,
description CLOB not null,
no_of_likes NUMBER(5),
no_of comments NUMBER(5),
no_of_views NUMBER(5),
user_id NUMBER(8,0),

CONSTRAINT pk_blog_blog_id PRIMARY KEY (blog_id),
CONSTRAINT fk_blog_user_id FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES USER_DETAILS (user_id)
)
Error report -
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Comment: If you type the code in a "Worksheet" tab, you will see a red underline in the offending line.

Comment: Are you sure the error is in SQL Developer, and not in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have made a typo:

```
no_of comments NUMBER(5),
```

should be

```
no_of_comments NUMBER(5),
```

Comment: Error starting at line : 1 in command -
create table Blog
(
blog_id NUMBER(8,0),
blog_name VARCHAR2(255) not null,
status VARCHAR2(50) DEFAULT 'PENDING',
create_date DATE default sysDate,
description CLOB not null,
no_of_likes NUMBER(5),
no_of comments NUMBER(5),
no_of_views NUMBER(5),
user_id NUMBER(8,0),

CONSTRAINT pk_blog_blog_id PRIMARY KEY (blog_id),
CONSTRAINT fk_blog_user_id FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES USER_DETAILS (user_id)
)
Error report -
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: It cant be both - table created and raised exception. According to your error message in this comment, you have still left the typo part. Are you not showing us all the code maybe? For me, the table was created without errors.